# React JS Route Path Not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I cant navigate to the Route path it doesn't respond to it I dont know why. Anyone know what is wrong with my code. It just load the landing page and that about it cant load other components

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer";
import Landing from "./components/layout/Landing";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import "./App.css";


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
          <div className="container">
          <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: [`Route.exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool) ie. `<Route path="/" component={Landing} exact/>`

Answer (score 2):

Add the `exact` to your intial route, else it gets caught in all the paths,

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
```

Comment: If it worked, can you pls accept the answer for stack overflow community...